# mysql/mariadb - syntax error: creating database function

Tags: mysql, database, function, phpmyadmin, mariadb

im having trouble finding the correct syntax i always having error #1064.

error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';

this is the code;

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `formula`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `formula`(iq INT, sq INT, ig INT) RETURNS INT

BEGIN

```
DECLARE result INT;

SET result = (iq-((sq/30)) * ig;

IF result >= 0 THEN
    RETURN result;
ELSEIF result < 0  THEN
    RETURN 0;
END IF;
```

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

i've searching for the answer in the web nothing i can find. what is the wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2):

you have a very small mistake in the code.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS formula$$
>
> CREATE FUNCTION formula(iq INT, sq INT, ig INT) RETURNS INT
>
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE result INT;
>
> SET result = (iq-((sq/30))) * ig; ---> You missed an closing bracket
> (")") here
>
> IF result >= 0 THEN
> RETURN result; ELSEIF result < 0  THEN
> RETURN 0; END IF; END; $$
>
> DELIMITER ;